# Search in fetch JSON API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I finally used fetch to get data from my API with React and got JSON in my console. Now I have another challenge.

I have a search component and I want to search in JSON that I got and show the result on screen. How can I do that?

This is what I've written so far:

```
class Global extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      query: "",
      items: []
    };
  }
  search() {
    let url = "/*my url*/";

    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
      cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        Authorization: "Bearer /*my key*/",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "accept"
      }
      // redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      // referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
      // body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="global">
        <h2>book Explore!</h2>
        <FormGroup>
          <InputGroup>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for a Branches"
              onChange={event => this.setState({ query: event.target.value })}
              onKeyPress={event => {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                  this.search();
                }
              }}
            />
            <InputGroup.Addon onClick={() => this.search()}>
              <Glyphicon glyph="search" />
            </InputGroup.Addon>
          </InputGroup>
          <Gallery items={this.state.items} />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the shape of the JSON.

Comment: {
    "status": {
        "response_code": 0,
        "response_message": "OK",
        "response_extra": null
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "BranchID": 1,
            "Name": "شعبه خورشید",
            "RegionNames": "نظر،فیض،میر،آپادانا،آبشار",
            "Latitude": "32.637717",
            "Longitude": "51.655215",
            "Image": "khorshid.jpg",
            "CreateDate": "2018-06-09 15:24:20",
            "Status": 1
        },
        ...

Comment: actually, in other word, i have an array that i saved it in "data" variable. now i want search in this array, what should i do???

Answer (score 0):

First thing is binding the search function in construcor block as shown below:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      query: "",
      items: []
    };
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }
```

Seems your code `<Gallery />` block depends on the value of this.state.items, once you got the response after fetch your search call assigns the required object to `items` state using `setState` function as shown below (2nd `then` block):

```
search() {
    let url = "/*my url*/";

    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
      cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        Authorization: "Bearer /*my key*/",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "accept"
      }

    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({items=json}));
  }
```